# How can I transfer data from one Xbox 360 slim to another slim?

Tags: xbox-360, hard-drive

I'm thinking about getting the Gears of War 3 limited edition console and I already have one of the new 360 S consoles. How can I transfer my data between the two?

I checked Google and couldn't find any new hard drive transfer cables, just the old ones. Normally I would just swap the hard drives but the Gears one comes with a 320 GB and I want to take advantage of the increased capacity.

I **really** don't want to move all the data with a 16 or 32 GB thumb drive, it would take forever. In theory, I should be able to just hook the two hard drives up to my PC (they have standard SATA connectors) and use Clonezilla. Has anyone tested this?

Any ideas for how to simplify this process are welcome.

Comment: Actually it would only take a couple of minutes to copy the user data to the thumb drive and over to the new XBox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft Store](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/en_US/pd/productID.216678500/parentCategoryID.50606600/categoryID.50790100/list.true), the Data Transfer Cable *will work* with Xbox 360 and Xbox 360 S consoles. Note that it will do regular to regular and regular to S, but *not* S to S.

As far as DLC licenses are concerned, there is an option in your accounts in the dashboard to transfer all of your licenses to the console you are on. It's in Guide > Settings > Account Management > License Transfer. There is also a webpage about license migration [here](http://www.xbox.com/support/licensemigration/).

---

**Update**: A new transfer cable for sending data from a slim to a slim [has just been announced](http://majornelson.com/2011/09/26/xbox-360-transfer-cable/). The Microsoft Store has yet to post the new cable, so you must contact customer support to order one at this time.

Comment: I tested xbox 360 S to xbox 360 S and it does not work. The plug for the hard drive not attached to the xbox only fits the older hard drives and is not a standard SATA plug.

Comment: It looks like I missed the footnote saying that it does not do S to S transfers, sorry @Kyle. :(

Comment: @Kyle Good news! There is a new cable! See answer.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should be able to, but I've not tested it myself and some arcade games and downloads are tied to the console, not the profile so these may not work on the new console.

An alternative is to copy all your profile and save games over on USB and re-download any games or dlc you want transferred on the new console.  It may take a while to download eveything again, but in terms of effort from you all you need to do is logon the xbox.com website and click on eveything you want to download, leave it overnight and job done!

May save yourself a lot of hassle in the long run with any issues to do with licenses and things not copying over properly etc.